# Difference between $1-P(A)$ and $P(A')$ in probability

Tags: probability

I have the following question:

> Before the distribution of certain statistical software, every fourth compact disk (CD) is tested for accuracy. The testing process consists of running four independent programs and checking the results. The failure rates for the four testing programs are, respectively, $0.01, 0.03, 0.02,$ and $0.01$.
> (a) What is the probability that a CD was tested and failed any test?

My solution:

We need to multiply the probability that a disc was test and multiply it by the probability that a disk fails any of the four tests. The probability that a disk is tested is $1/4$, the probability that any given disk fails the test, in others words probability of programs $A$ or $B$ or $C$ or $D$ failing is:
$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+P(D)-P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D)$

=$0.07-(0.01*0.01*0.02*0.03)$
=$0.06999994$

so our final answer would be $0.25*0.06999994=0.017499985$

However what they did was different:
They took the probability that all 4 programs run successfully and that is $0.99*0.99*0.98*0.97$ and did $1-(0.99*0.99*0.98*0.97)$ that which yields $ 0.06831696$ and that isn't the same as my answer in this step ($0.06999994$)

What is this difference due to? Where did I go wrong?

Note: the 2 final answers would be the same after rounding ($0.17$) but I want to know where things went wrong before.

Comment: $P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+P(D)-P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D)$ is wrong

Comment: @Arthur mind explaining why?

Comment: Draw a Venn diagram for just three events, and see that it is not $$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)-P(A \cap B \cap C)$$Conclude that your generalisation to four events is likely also flawed. (The true expression quickly becomes messy, and contains $2^n-1$ terms.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that you're failing to account for the possibility that a disk fails exactly two or three tests, so you're (slightly) undercounting the failure rate.

Comment: and how could I have done that? I think it might be 4 times (0.01∗0.01∗0.02∗0.03) but that still yields an unexact answer

Comment: The book's solution is the way this sort of problem is typically done, but if you want to do it the hard way, you'd use the principle of inclusion and exclusion to add and subtract, as appropriate, failures of multiple tests.

Comment: thank you for this

Answer (score 4):

The correct probability for at least one to fail is, by inclusion-exclusion,
$$P(A)+P(B)+P(C)+P(D)\\-P(A\cap B)-P(A\cap C)-P(A\cap D)-P(B\cap C)-P(B\cap D)-P(C\cap D)\\+P(A\cap B\cap C)+P(A\cap B\cap D)+P(A\cap C\cap D)+P(B\cap C\cap D)\\
-P(A\cap B\cap C\cap D).$$
Assuming the events are independent, this is exactly what you would get if you multiplied out $(1-P(A))(1-P(B))(1-P(C))(1-P(D))$ and subtracted it from $1$.